# C++ Qt SQL Query length limit for Oracle

Tags: c++, sql, oracle, qt

there is a limit of SQL query length when we use the Qt code as follows:

```
QString queryStr = "... long SELECT statement ...";  // with over 8000 chars.
QSqlQuery query( queryStr
    , new QSqlDatabase( QSqlDatabase::addDatabase( "QOCI", "connectionName" ) );
if ( !query.isActive() ) {
    return false;  // for long querys we end up here.
} else {
    return true;
}
```

Is this a 8K border?

Comment: what do you mean by 8k border. you need to look at the DB itself, in this case Oracle. Can you do it directly? if it's not the case then it has nothing to do with Qt

Comment: @UmNyobe yes it depends on Oracle.
I tested it in the Oracle SQL Developer it returns the exception:
"maximum number of expressions in a list is 1000".
Now it is the question: Is it the right handling to execute queries in Qt in the constructor? Why didn't I get an exception?
Kind regards, S

Answer (score 0):

The limit of a SQL query depends on many factors, including database configuration, disk space and memory. So there is no fixed query length limit.

Some other factors may affect limits, such as the maximum levels of subqueries. You can see [this](http://awads.net/wp/2010/02/15/oracle-database-limits-you-may-not-know-about/) for some limits on Oracle.

In your case i don't know what is your query. May be your problem is not the length of query. There may be some syntax problems. Also you don not call the exec() function of QSqlQuery to retrieve results.

Comment: Also good is following site:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/limits003.htm
@Nejat: Yes, it was the SQL. The problem was the maximum count of elments in a list.